# grep does not work in particular folder on centos?

Tags: centos, grep

It's a bit strange with the grep command. When I am in the mail folder, it always produces help text. At first, I thought I had wrong synxtax but it is working on its parent folder.
What could be the cause? TIA!

```
[xx]$ grep "abc" *.out
grep: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
[xx]$ cd ..
[xx]$ grep "abc" mail/*.out
mail/0940-cron-mail.out:News 3598...h...N
```

Comment: Could help : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364922/grep-getting-confused-by-filenames-with-dashes

Answer (score 3):

You have a file in that directory that starts with the character '-'.

When you grep in the directory, the * expands out all the filenames, and grep interprets the one with the leading - as an option, and fails to parse it.

When your grep includes the directory path, the * still expands the filenames out, but now the - is in the middle of the path+filename, so isn't interpreted as a commandline option

Comment: So OP needs to say `grep "abc" -- *.out`

Comment: Thanks! that helps! I tried this and it works too. grep "ab" ./*.out